# How to make overlay image only visible in mkmapview?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have an jpg map image of one country, i added it into the mkmapview as a overlay. The problem is i want image overlya only visible in mkmapview. Other parts are can not be shown. But i want scroll is enabled and zoom is enabled. Any solutions?

Comment: @thejaz yes i have solved this by using the Tiles concept.

Comment: Care to post the solution on this question? Would appreciate it!